# Quadratic equations - Fastest way to find the value of d

Tags: quadratics

$\frac{2d^2-d-10}{d^2+7d+10} = \frac{d^2-4d+3}{d^2+2d-15}$

What is the optimal solution for finding the value of d?

Comment: Both quadratics on the left factor, and have a common factor. Are you sure you entered the formulas correctly on the right-hand side?

Comment: @rogerl Sorry! My mistake, I typed a + instead of a -

Comment: Well, now you can factor both quadratics on the right as well, and they have a common factor. That should make things much easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Factor the quadratics.  You can pull out $x+5$ on the left and $x-3$ on the right.

Answer (score 1):

Your expression can be written as

$$ \frac{(2d-5)(d+2)}{(d+5)(d+2)} = \frac{(d-1)(d-3)}{(d+5)(d-3)}.$$

Can you see how to proceed from here?